# Hide part and chapter headings

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

Is there a way to completely hide the `\part` and `\chapter` headings when they are called (but still show them in the toc)? Maybe using `titlesec`?

**Note:**

I'm using something like this to capture the chapter headings and reuse them:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Define \chaphead to be used in section headings
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\newcommand\temphead{}
\newcommand\chaphead{}
\renewcommand\chapter[2][\temphead]{%
    \renewcommand\temphead{#2}%
    \renewcommand\chaphead{#2}%
    \oldchapter[#1]{#2}}

\newcommand*\Hide{%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {}{}{0pt}{}
%\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\large} % format
  {\chaphead, section \thesection} % label
  {10pt} %sep
  {} %before
}

\begin{document}

{
\Hide
\chapter{A first chapter}
\section{A first section}
\lipsum
}

\chapter{A second chapter}
\section{A second section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

When activating `\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}`, it seems `\chaphead` is not capture anymore.

Comment: The headings must not be typeset, but the space they occupied must remain?

Comment: I mean to hide the chapter name completely, so it doesn't appear in the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you can use the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; its `explicit` option allows you to remove the titles:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand*\Hide{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\part}
  {}{}{0pt}{}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

{
\Hide
\part{A test part}
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{Test section}
}

\part{A test part}
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{Test section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright, that removes the chapter headings... but it also removes the section headings, and the chapter headings outside of the environment in which I did the call to `\titleformat`...

Comment: You can keep the changes local by using the grouping mechanism; I've edited my example to reflect this approach (and defining a command to simplify the work).

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using an environment already, that should limit the scope, shouldn't it?

Comment: Without your actual relevant code it's really hard to tell. Why don't you add to your question all the necessary elements (in the sense of a minimal working example) affecting your request?

Comment: Alright, I found my mistake (forgot to use `#1` to indicate the headings when using `explicit`). Now, it won't show the headings, but it will still make empty pages. Can I get rid of these?

Comment: Sure, instead of using the `\part` command, you can add the corresponding ToC entry manually with the help of the `\addcontentsline` command.

Comment: ... or change the "class" of `\part` to straight: `\titleclass{\part}{straight}`.

Comment: I meant for the `\chapter` part. I can't just add the contents, because I'm using the counter and chapter name in other macros, so I need the chapter to be properly registered, but still not show in the text.

Comment: Using `\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}` removes the blank pages, but it doesn't register the chapter name (it does register the chapter number though).

Comment: I added a note about a bit of code I have already which might play a role in this issue...

Comment: Again, without knowledge of your actual relevant code, this process of guessing is totally useless and time wasting... as I already suggested, add a minimal working example of your relevant code.

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

I extended and changed the example for class `srcartcl` to the following solution (You find the one for class `srcbook` below):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

% change part format
\titleformat{\part}[drop]{}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{One}
\blindtext
\section{Apple}
\blindtext
\section{Peach}
\blindtext

\part{Two}
\blindtext
\section{Red}
\blindtext
\section{Green}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Btw.: It works nicely together with the counter reset from [Adendum 2 in this first answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124755/how-to-reset-section-counter).

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
```

Here the code with `scrbook`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

% change part format
\titleformat{\part}[drop]{}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[drop]{}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{One}
\blindtext
\chapter{Fruits}
\blindtext
\section{Apple}
\blindtext
\section{Peach}
\blindtext

\part{Two}
\blindtext
\chapter{Colours}
\blindtext
\section{Red}
\blindtext
\section{Green}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```