# To develop part command in sectioning

Tags: sectioning, parts

I want to change Conzalo's command little ([How to reset a section counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124757/13173)) by removing the representation of Part [number] in the document:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\centering}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{\Large}{\LARGE}{}{}
\renewcommand
% \partname{Topic}
\makeatother
```

I use the part command for Lectures, Practicals, Master Topics. 
My table of contents

[image]

and my document

[image]

I do not really understand the command because disabling these two lines do nothing:

```
% \xpatchcmd{\@part}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\centering}{}{}
% \xpatchcmd{\@part}{\Large}{\LARGE}{}{}
```

I want to remove the representation of Part and number.

**How can you remove the representation of the Part headings every time you use part?**

Comment: You want to remove "Part XX", but still keep the heading `Practicals` and `CIRCULATION and HEART`? What about the entries in the ToC? What other packages do you use that influence headings (like, perhaps, [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec))? What about supplying a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)... pretty please?

Comment: Gonzalo's answer is exactly what I was looking for. I want to maintain those Practicals and Lectures -notifications in the table of contest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
  \def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
    \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \LARGE \bfseries #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\@addtoreset{section}{part}    
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Practicals}
\section{Section I}
content
\subsection{Subsection I} 
content

\part{CIRCULATION and HEART}
\section{Section I}
content
\subsection{Subsection I} 
content

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the `section` counter shouldn't reset at each part, delete the line

```
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and clear answer! You are awesome!

Comment: @Masi You're welcome. I made a simplication to the answer (suggested by Werner); the new code is shorter.

Comment: I extended this question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163030/representation-of-subsubsection-numbers to correspond better the structure which I need for the exercise.