# Hiding the chapter heading messes up the TOC for included files

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, include

I wish to start a chapter without displaying the header at all. The side effects, however, should be preserved, namely the `chapter` counter should be stepped, and a TOC entry created.

Note that @Dirk's answer for [Hide part and chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16050/hide-part-and-chapter-headings) still produces some white space in place of the heading. Plus, I would rather not use the `titlesec` package.

To this end, this works fine:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{Ch1}\stepcounter{chapter}
\section{Sec11}
\section{Sec12}

\cleardoublepage
\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{Ch2}\stepcounter{chapter}
\section{Sec21}
\section{Sec22}

\end{document}
```

However, things change when I `\include` the sections:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{filecontents}{Sec11.tex}
\section{Sec11}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Sec12.tex}
\section{Sec12}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Sec21.tex}
\section{Sec21}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Sec22.tex}
\section{Sec22}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{Ch1}\stepcounter{chapter}
\include{Sec11}
\include{Sec12}

\cleardoublepage
\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{Ch2}\stepcounter{chapter}
\include{Sec21}
\include{Sec22}

\end{document}
```

Now, the TOC is messed up:
[image]

How does this come about. And is there a nice (simple) way to fix this?

Comment: Use `\input` instead `\include` at least for the first section in a new chapter.

Comment: I see that this circumvents this problem. But I am bound to `\include`.

Comment: If you write `\cleardoublepage` after `\addtocentrydefault` the table of contents is correct except for the page number of Ch2 (4). Therefore it would be better to use esdd's suggestion (see [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original answer** (Below is an update with a maybe better suggestion)

Here is a suggestion patching `\@include`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@chaptertocentry{}% initialize \@chaptertocentry
\newcommand*\chaptertocentry[1]{\def\@chaptertocentry{#1}}% command to set \@chaptertocentry

\xpatchcmd\@include{\@input@}
  {\ifstr{\@chaptertocentry}{}{}
    {\cleardoublepage\stepcounter{chapter}\addchaptertocentry{}{\@chaptertocentry}}% add the toc entry
    \@input@
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

\xapptocmd\@include{\def\@chaptertocentry{}}{}{\PatchFailed}% reset \@chaptertocentry
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chaptertocentry{Ch1}
\include{Sec11}
\include{Sec12}

\chaptertocentry{Ch2}
\include{Sec21}
\include{Sec22}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

`\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{<chapter title>}` writes `\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\nonumberline <chapterline>}{<pagenumber>}}` to the main aux file, *when the current page is shipped out* (to get the right pagenumber in TOC).

`\include` writes *immediatley* an `\@input` command for the own aux file of the included the tex file to the main aux file. So, if the `\addtocentrydefault` command appears on the same page as `\include` the `\@input` for the special aux goes the main aux before the `\@writefile{toc}...`.

The resulting main aux file of your example is:

```
\relax 
\providecommand*\new@tpo@label[2]{}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\nonumberline Ch1}{1}}
\@input{Sec11.aux}
\@input{Sec12.aux}
\@input{Sec21.aux}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\nonumberline Ch2}{5}}
\@input{Sec22.aux}
\global\@namedef{scr@dte@section@lastmaxnumwidth}{18.37163pt}
```

As you can see "Ch1" gets the wrong page number "1" because `\addcontentsline` is excecuted on the (last) page of the TOC.

In your MWE there is a `\cleardoublepage` before `\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{Ch2}\stepcounter{chapter}` which inserts no content in the document. So there is no page break between this command and the following `\include{Sec21}`: `\@input{Sec21.aux}` is immediatly written while `\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\nonumberline Ch2}{5}}` is written when page 5 is shipped out. So all headings in "Sec21" appear in the TOC before "Ch2".

AFAIK this behaviour can not be changed. So you have to ensure that `\@writefile{toc}...` command goes to the aux file of the included tex file. This can be done by the patch in my original answer above. Alternatively package `scrlfile` can be used:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{scrlfile}
\newcommand\hiddenchapter[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \stepcounter{chapter}%
  \addchaptertocentry{}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\BeforeFile{Sec11.tex}{\hiddenchapter{Ch1}}
\include{Sec11}
\include{Sec12}

\BeforeFile{Sec21.tex}{\hiddenchapter{Ch2}}
\include{Sec21}
\include{Sec22}
\end{document}
```

The resulting main aux file is

```
\relax 
\providecommand*\new@tpo@label[2]{}
\@input{Sec11.aux}
\@input{Sec12.aux}
\@input{Sec21.aux}
\@input{Sec22.aux}
\global\@namedef{scr@dte@section@lastmaxnumwidth}{18.37163pt}
```

and the Sec21.aux:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\nonumberline Ch2}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}Sec21}{5}}
\@setckpt{Sec21}{
\setcounter{page}{6}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{enumi}{0}
\setcounter{enumii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiv}{0}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\setcounter{mpfootnote}{0}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\setcounter{paragraph}{0}
\setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
}
```

Comment: I've run into this problem again, and appreciate your solution once more. But can you explain the underlying problem? – Why can the TOC contentsline not just be written to the `.toc` file immediately?

Comment: See my updated answer with an additional new suggestion.

Comment: Great, illustrative answer! Thanks so much! I'm sorry I cannot upvote again, I hope others will do it..