# Appendix’ contents shown under wrong heading in Table of Contents

Tags: sectioning, chapters, appendices

I am changing a pre-built template for my thesis. There is a main file named `thesis.tex` in which all the chapter files, references files and appendices files are included. The structure of this file is as follows

```
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
\include{chapter7}


% NEED TO CHANGE THE SECTION NUMBER FOR REFERENCES ACCORDINGLY
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{8 \hskip 3.55em References}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}  
\bibliography{references}

% COMMENT THE LINES ABOUT APPENDIX OUT IF YOU DO NOT HAVE THIS SECTION.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                                 %
%                            APPENDICES                           %
%                                                                 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage\pagestyle{plain}
\theappendix

% NEED TO CHANGE THE SECTION NUMBER FOR REFERENCES ACCORDINGLY.
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{9 \hskip 3.55em Appendices}

\include{appendix1}
%\include{appendix2}
\include{appendix3}
```

**Problem:**
The problem is with the appendices section. My first appedix contains some sections and figures. When i add this section to main file, the contents of this appendix are shown wrongly under other chapter in table of contents.

[image]

As you can see that the contents of Appendix are being shown under references chapter. I want them to be shown either under appendices section or completely hide them. What could be the possible solution?

Comment: Aside: You can/should use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{8} References}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{9} Appendices}`.

Comment: Nothing seems amiss with your placement of the appendix within the ToC. Did you compile at least twice to ensure that the ToC entries have settled?

Comment: I am using sharelatex for editing and I have compiled many times in a single session, also downloaded the pdf. Same issue persists.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a link to the project. It's difficult to assess the issue without seeing something we can work with fully.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of the behavior is eg in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386799. But the OP there uses a KOMA-Script class and its `\addchaptertocentry` command.

Suggestion: Replacing `\include{appendix1}` by `\input{appendix1}` should solve your issue.

---

If you really must use `\include`, then load package `scrlfile` and use:

```
\BeforeFile{appendix1.tex}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{9 \hskip 3.55em Appendices}}%  needs package scrlfile
\include{appendix1}
```

BTW: Your manual setting of the chapter number looks strange.