# Implement hiding part and chapter titles from this solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16050/hide-part-and-chapter-headings

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

Hi I am trying to hide all `\Chapter` `\section` and `\subsection` headers and titles utilising the solution given here [Hide part and chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16050/hide-part-and-chapter-headings)

I have also looked at other possible solutions but they don't maintain the integrity of the toc, therefore this solution appears the most suitable. However, I cannot get the solution to work even using an MWE as it throws up `\hide` as an Undefined control sequence. ^^I\hide.

Would someone be able to help please? Here is a copy of my MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt ]{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand*\Hide{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\part}
{}{}{0pt}{}
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek,hebrew}

\begin{document}
{
\hide
 \chapter{Introduction}

 \section{Background Statement}
 }

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Well, you define `\Hide` but use `\hide`.

Comment: Thanks @PeterWilson I knew I was missing something, just didn't realise it was that simple!